# =delete for user defined member functions apart from constructor, assignment operator c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, delete-operator

In C++11, we use "= delete" as not to allow the constructors and operator overloaded member functions to be invoked implicitly while doing some operations(change of dataype/assignment of objects).

```
class color{
 public:    
 color(){cout<<"color constructed called"<<endl;}
 color(int a){};
 color(float)=delete;
 color& operator = (color &a) = delete;
 virtual void paint() = delete;  //What is the use of delete in this function
 //void paint() = delete; The above virtual is not mandatory, just a generic scenario.
 virtual void paints () final {};
};
```

I have used delete on  user defined member function in the above example. It says that we can define the paint() function, hence no other function can call it.

Want to know if there is there is any scenarios in which this type of function declaration(paint) would be useful/recommended.

Comment: I don't see any use of `virtual void paint() = delete;` Why would you delete a virtual function? Just don't declare it in the first place.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you wondering if there is *generally* a use for `= delete` on member functions, or *specifically* for `virtual` member functions?

Answer (score 3):

So that nothing benefits from this overload.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Nyan {
    int omg(int x) { return x + 2; }
};

struct Meow {
    int omg(int x) { return x + 2; }
    int omg(double) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Nyan n;
    Meow m;
    std::cout << n.omg(40) << std::endl;
    std::cout << m.omg(40) << std::endl;
    std::cout << n.omg(40.5) << std::endl;
    // std::cout << m.omg(40.5) << std::endl; // commented out for a reason
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking what delete is for in general, but rather the specific delete of the paint virtual function, the oddity of which is highlighted by @DimChtz's comment.

Comment: @schulmaster This actually points out exactly why you would sometimes want to do it. In one case the implicit conversion will be performed, but in the other it will not.

Comment: Deleted functions *do* participate in and join the overload set.  Then, when the compiler resolves the overloads, if it turns out that the deleted function is the best match, it's an error.  (If the deleted function didin't participate in the overload set, then your commented out code would match the omg(int) function and would compile.  Clearly it does not.)

Comment: @schulmaster Don't assume what the OP wants - if it's unclear, ask the OP (the OP does *not* want the specific case of deleting the `virtual`).

Answer (score 2):

- Provide stricter input arguments checks:

```
 void foo(void *){}

 void foo(int) = delete;

 foo(0); // error
```

- Mark methods as "explicitly not implemented", this may be useful when a family of classes has a certain function but this particular class does not provide it for performance or other reasons:

```
class my_list
{
    // you should use other container if you need constant time size
    public: size_t size(void) = delete;     
};
```

- As a final step of function deprecation. Some even use a dedicated macro.

Comment: Same comments as for @bipll's answer.

Comment: OP is asking about `virtual void paint() = delete;` not this `color(float)=delete;`

Comment: @DimChtz OP is asking why you would want to sometime delete a function, and this gives a good example of just that.

Comment: @super: OP isn't asking why you would want to delete functions -- he is explicitly asking about the `paint` one, which is `virtual`, not about deleted functions in general.

Comment: @Acorn Deleteing a virtual function and deleting a non-virtual function can be done for the same reasons. It's about what the effect is and **why** you want to do it.

Comment: @Acorn All 3 cases I've listed are perfectly applicable to `virtual` functions.

Comment: @super: Agreed, but as I read it, OP is wondering about what would be the point of deleting a virtual function at the top of a hierarchy; not what is the point of deleting (virtual or not) functions (specially since OP seems already aware of deleting functions for other purposes, like the ones stated here).

Comment: @VTT: Of course, but I doubt OP is wondering about these general cases that are applicable to `virtual` functions -- it seems the question is about what *additional* use cases could exist for the *particular* case of `virtual` functions. Otherwise, the question is trivial (and most likely a duplicate).

Comment: @Acorn OP has added a code comment stating that presence of `virtual` is not relevant.

Comment: @VTT: Indeed -- then I agree it seems OP is just asking for the general case. The question can be re-written and simplified, then. Reverting the downvotes as needed.